# node-restify parent path handler

Tags: node.js, restify

If I have two path, let's say `/path/one` and `path/two`, and I wan't they both handled by a parent handler first, then handled by their specific handler. How can I achieve it. The code below won't work. Their specific handler never run.

```
const restify = require('restify');
const app = restify.createServer();
app.get('/path/:type', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.type + ' handled by parent handler');
    next();
});

app.get('/path/one', function (req, res) {
    console.log('one handler');
    res.end();
});

app.get('/path/two', function (req, res) {
    console.log('two handler');
    res.end();
});

app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('Server running');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this kind of "fall through routing" is not supported in restify. The first route handler that matches the request is executed. But you have some alternatives to implement the given use case

**Named `next` Calls**

Instead of calling `next()` without a parameter you call `next(req.params.type)` to invoke route `one` or `two`. Caveats: In case no route is registered for a type restify will send a 500 response.

```
const restify = require('restify');
const app = restify.createServer();

app.get('/path/:type', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.type + ' handled by parent handler');
    next(req.params.type);
});

app.get({ name: 'one', path: '/path/one' }, function (req, res) {
    console.log('one handler');
    res.end();
});

app.get({ name: 'two', path: '/path/two' }, function (req, res) {
    console.log('two handler');
    res.end();
});

app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('Server running');
});
```

**Common handlers (aka Middleware in express)**

Since restify has no mounting feature like express does we need to extract the `type` param from the current route manually:

```
const restify = require('restify');
const app = restify.createServer();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.method == 'GET' && req.route && req.route.path.indexOf('/path') == 0) {
    var type = req.route.path.split('/')[2];

    console.log(type + ' handled by parent handler');
  }

  next();
});

app.get('/path/one', function (req, res) {
    console.log('one handler');
    res.end();
});

app.get('/path/two', function (req, res) {
    console.log('two handler');
    res.end();
});

app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('Server running');
});
```